# Integrating multivariable inverse functions?

Tags: integration, inverse

I'm completely stumped on an integration problem in my work which, I suspect might be easy, but I have no clue as to how to approach it. It goes like this:

Can I simplify $\int y(u,x)dx$, where $u(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(x,y)$ ?

I feel like the derivative and antiderivative should cancel in places, but I don't know how to handle the inverse relationship between $u(x,y)$ and $y(x,u)$.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Hugh

EDIT: After originally attempting to post the issue in a more abstract manner, here's the exact situation I am dealing with:

$\int y(u,x)^2dx$, where $u(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} v(x,y)$ and $v(x,y) = ax\left(\frac{1}{(y^2+x^2)^{1/2}} + \frac{b}{(y^2+x^2)^{3/2}}\right)$.

The issue is that, while I can carry out the derivation to find $u(x,y)$, I can't isolate $y^2$ in order to integrate it. Hence, I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid doing the derivation/integration altogether.

Comment: I’m not sure there’s way to simplify this in general... Have you tried assuming simple functional forms for $v$ to see what the integral is? Maybe you might find a pattern you can generalise from there.

Comment: No you can't. Is this the exact expression you're dealing with? If not I would advise you to post the specific expression as generalities may lack some properties enjoyed by special cases.

Comment: OK thanks for the pointers. I have edited the original post to include the specific expression.

Comment: It's much easier to isolate $y^2$ from $v(x,y)$ than $u(x,y)$. So I think it could help to say $\int u(x,y) dx = v(x,y)$, and then isolate $y^2$ in terms of $x$ and $\int u(x,y) dx$.
Then, I think one can carry out $\int y^2(\int(x,y)dx,x)$ using integration by parts: $\int m n^\prime = m n - \int m^\prime n$, where $m=\int u(x,y)dx = v(x,y)$, $m^\prime = u(x,y)$, $n^\prime$ is whatever is being multiplied with $\int u(x,y)dx$ and $n$ is its integral. It seems to work for a simpler case of $v(x,y)$, so I'll try the full expression next.